# Converting seconds to date time String

Tags: android

I have seconds from epoch time and want to convert it to `Day-Month-Year HH:MM`
I have tried following but it gives me wrong value.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(seconds*1000);
String dateString = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + ", "+.......
```

Above code is not working properly am i doing anything wrong here.

For example if `seconds = 1299671538`
then it generates time string as `Friday, December 12, 1969` which is wrong it should display `Wednesday, March 09, 2011`

Comment: How is it wrong?  People cannot help you without more information

Comment: Your seconds value is wrong - it gives the correct date.

Comment: I did not get you, have you tried running this code?

Comment: I ran this:        `System.out.println(new Date(1299671538*1000));
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime());`

Comment: Still not getting you, I have not used `Date` anywhere in my code are you suggesting me to use `Date`??

Comment: the problem is that the number is too large for an int

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> For example if seconds = 1299671538 then it generates time string as Friday, December 12, 1969 which is wrong it should display Wednesday, March 09, 2011

You have integer overflow. Just use the following (notice "L" after 1000 constant):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(seconds*1000L);
String dateString = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + ", "+.......
```

or better use SimpleDateFormat class:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(seconds * 1000L));
```

this will give you the following date string for your original seconds input:
`Wednesday, March 9, 2011 13:52`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

instead of

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

because UTC time from seconds depends on Timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a calendar in this case, you can simply use the constructor `new Date(1000 * seconds)`

Then use a SimpleDateFormat to create a String to display it.

For a full explanation on using SimpleDateFormat go [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

The answer to this question though is that you need to use long values instead of ints.

```
new Date(1299674566000l)
```

If you don't believe me, run this:

```
    int secondsInt = 1299674566;
    System.out.println(new Date(secondsInt *1000));
    long secondsLong = 1299674566;
    System.out.println(new Date(secondsLong *1000));
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example, as i am not able to figure it out, that how to use Date with SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: Yes I am using Long vales not Int, but still my out put is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that answer from @Idolon is working fine, simple snippet is below...

```
long created = 1300563523;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(created * 1000L));
```

using SimpleDateFormat is better way, change the format as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Won't it work wihtout Calendar, like below? Haven't run this piece of code, but guess it should work .

```
CharSequence theDate = DateFormat.format("Day-Month-Year HH:MM", objDate);
```