# How to convert String to Date in android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

i convert String to Date as:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
String datenow="20120917121823";
Date date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(datenow);
```

datenow is 12 pm. why after convert it's "Mon Sep 17 00:18:23 GMT+07:00 2012"

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: You're not using the proper format. Hour is HH
Same for minutes

Comment: Read the docs for SimpleDateFormat. They have a table of formats and their corresponding symbols.

Comment: Why in the world is my answer converted to a comment when it's the actual answer. Oh the wonders of the world...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because hh in hours grabs hours from 1 to 12 you can see the encoding [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You should be using:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String datenow="20120917121823";
Date date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(datenow);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        String temp = "Mon Sep 17 00:18:23 GMT+07:00 2012";
        Date expiry = formatter.parse(temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Shrikant- but String of me is "20120917121823".

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245741/converting-seconds-to-date-time-string)