# Android : Convert seconds to year, day, hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: java, android, timestamp, epoch

I'm working on an Android project, using a JSON file already encoded.

So I've got this:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "mag": 1.29,
    "place": "10km SSW of Idyllwild, CA",
    "time": 1388620296020,
    "updated": 1457728844428
  }
}
```

And I want to convert `time` in year, day, hours and seconds.
I know there are many topics talking about my problem but I already tried them without success.

Comment: `I already tried them without success` show what you've tried, so we can help fixing it. Untill you show, we can't believe that you've tried.

Comment: Not quite sure if I have understood you: Do you want to express the time difference **between your `time`-variable and now-timestamp** in years, days, hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert epoch time to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740972/convert-epoch-time-to-date)

Comment: The linked question has milliseconds rather than seoncds, but the conversion should be trivial; in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502808/5772882), for example, just use `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` instead of `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`.

Comment: Agree with @VladMatvienko that a better starting point for assisting you would be in what way the other questions didn’t help. As your questions stands there’s hardly anything we can add here that hasn’t been said before, so you just risk getting another 5 answers that you can try without success.

Answer (score 1):

In **Android**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes, together with [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

This API provides a good way to work with dates, much better than the outdated `Date` and `Calendar` (The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and they're being replaced by the new APIs).

To get a date from a timestamp value (assuming that `1388620296020` is the number of **milliseconds** from unix epoch), you can use the `org.threeten.bp.Instant` class:

```
// create the UTC instant from 1388620296020
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1388620296020L);
System.out.println(instant); // 2014-01-01T23:51:36.020Z
```

The output is `2014-01-01T23:51:36.020Z`, because `Instant` is always in UTC. If you want to convert this to a date/time in another timezone, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` class and create a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println(z); // 2014-01-02T00:51:36.020+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

The output will be `2014-01-02T00:51:36.020+01:00[Europe/Paris]` (the same UTC instant converted to Paris timezone).

Please note that the API avoids the use of 3-letter timezones names (like `ECT` or `CST`), because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). Always prefer to use the full names (like `Europe/Paris` or `America/Los_Angeles`, defined by [IANA database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) - you can get all the available names by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

If you want to print the date in a different format, you can use a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` (please refer to [javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see all the possible formats):

```
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
System.out.println(fmt.format(z)); // 02/01/2014 00:51:36.020 +0100
```

Answer (score 1):

You have integer overflow. Just use the following (notice "L" after 1000 constant):

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(seconds*1000L);
String dateString = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + ", "+.......
```

see this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246444/7161543

Answer (score 0):

Can be something like ;

```
long jsondate = 1388620296020L;
Date dt = new Date (jsondate); 
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sd.format(dt));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but that doesn't work ^^'


I tried something else and that work :D :

Long timeConvert = Long.parseLong(time);
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(timeConvert);
time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(timeConvert);

Comment: Please add "L" after long number

Comment: Thanks a lot however :)

Comment: No problemmm :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long uptime = 1388620296020;

long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
.toDays(uptime);
uptime -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
.toHours(uptime);
uptime -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
.toMinutes(uptime);
 uptime -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
.toSeconds(uptime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is shorter:

```
    long lg=1388620296020l;
    Date date = new Date(lg);
```