# How to give date time a format?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, date-format

I am fetching date time from my API in which I am facing problem how I can set this date time to textView. I want to show this DateTime in this format how I can do this 9 Sep 2018. here is my snapshot in which date format is given. that format is coming from my API. [Date time Format in API snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCdtf.png)
I have uploaded the snapshot of textView

how I can set the review date to text View. Thank you in advance
how I can set this to my textView

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245741/converting-seconds-to-date-time-string

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: I think the time should be the only number not like `Date(...)`

Comment: Please paste your JSON snapshot (or what your input is) as text in the question rather than linking to an image. Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json date to java date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956396/convert-json-date-to-java-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you ask a solution**

```
String date = "/Date(1536566908220)/";
String milli = date.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(milli)) {
    long time = Long.parseLong(milli);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(time);
    System.out.println(formattedDate); // 13-4-2015 10:59:26
}
```

**If you ask a suggestion.**

> This is not a good format to receive date  `"/Date(778844555)/"`.

- either make it totally millisecond like `1536566913832` from backend.
- or make it a string date format only like `13-4-2015 10:59:26`

Comment: Nice to provide a suggestion for a better format. However for the vast majority of purposes the best format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), for example `2015-04-13T10:59:26Z` or in case of a date only just `2018-09-09`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I just showed an example, you can please edit my answer.